# left join using linq and lambda

Tags: sql-server, linq, lambda

I have employee table, which looks as below

[image]

I have employeedetails table, which looks as below

[image]

I have performed left join using SQL query, it works well.

```
SELECT E.* FROM Employee E
LEFT JOIN EmployeeDetails ED ON ED.EmpId = E.EmpId
WHERE ED.EmpDetailsId IS NULL
```

[image]

I need same result as above using LINQ to Entities and also lambda expression. How to do these using both ways (LINQ and LAMBDA)

Comment: Where will you be calling the LINQ/Lambda expression from? C#? If so, what are the corresponding classes?

Comment: I will be using it in webforms using entity framework, and i have employees and employeedetails entities

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525830/linq-lambda-left-join-with-an-inner-join)